# Unable to find Emmet in package control in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet, package-control

I'm trying to install Emmet via Package Control in Sublime Text 3 but whenever I search for it it just doesn't show up.

Any ideas? Am I missing a repository maybe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be that you've already installed Emmet. First, go to `Preferences -> Package Settings` and see if there's an `Emmet` submenu there. Alternatively, `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User` has a list of all installed packages. Finally, you can check your `Installed Packages` folder for an `Emmet.sublime-package` file - go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open your `Packages` directory, navigate one level up, and `Installed Packages` should be right there.

If you find Emmet at one of those locations, but for some reason it's not working for you, go to `Preferences -> Package Control` to open up that section of the Command Palette, select `Package Control: Remove Package`, then type in ***`emmet`*** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to remove it. You should then be able to select `Package Control: Install Package` from the Command Palette and pick Emmet from the list.

Comment: You were right. It was already installed but just not working properly, for whatever reason. I removed it, installed it again, and now it's all back to normal. Thanks!

Comment: personally it's not install and I can't find it, so what can be the reason ?

Answer (score -1):

I experienced a similar issue where it *appeared* emmet was installed, but it wasn't.
Maybe for quicker verification do this:
click `sublime test > pref > package control (from sublime) >` and type `emmet`
 If emmet is not listed:
click `pref > pack control > "install package" > emmet`